Starting point for troubleshooting responsiveness discrepancy between RDP on macbook air vs macbook pro
I'm finding that my older, slower Macbook Air's responsiveness on Microsoft Remote Desktop Client to my Ubuntu server is significantly better than that of my newer Macbook Pro's (e.g. clicking a GUI window on my remote session registers faster on the first client; they both use the same X display session). My overall internet speed on both devices is comparable.
This makes no sense to me - they are on the same network, have similar major version of operating system, same client app etc. If anything, I'd expect the reverse, that is my Macbook air to be slower.
I know this is a vague question but what would be the starting point for troubleshooting this? I know how to troubleshoot connectivity with netcat, ping etc. but this is odd.

Other notes:

I used to use the newer macbook pro for work which had various security profiles installed. But I have removed all of them and see no evidence in other behaviour that there are remnants of some private cloud. And I'm not exposing the RDP port publicly so I doubt it would be taking a different route.


It turns out that the client screen resolution has a big effect on responsiveness. Unmaximizing my RDP client window solved the problem.
Moral of the story: not sure. Everything contributes to bandwidth consumption?!
